# Cast QList of derived to QList of base

Tags: c++, qt

I have these classes:

```
class IParameter {};
class ModuleParameter : public IParameter {};
```

Now I have QList of derived:

```
QList<ModuleParameter*> list;
```

When I cast single item it's ok:

```
IParameter *p = list[0]; // ok
```

When I cast the list I've got an error.

```
QList<IParameter*> *list = static_cast<QList<IParameter*>*>(&list);
```

`Invalid static_cast from type QList<ModuleParameter*>* to type QList<IParameter*>*`.

So, how can I cast?

Comment: consider std::copy or std::transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QList` is a template without common base class type and `QList<ModuleParameter*>` is a type unrelated to `QList<IParameter*>`, you can't access `QList<ModuleParameter*>` polymorphically through a pointer to `QList<IParameter*>`.  What you trying to do is impossible to do this way.

Instead you may store pointers to `ModuleParameter` in `QList<IParameter*>` and use cast when accessing them.

Comment: So, is all you outlined right for any template class?

Comment: @maestro It's for any type. Type created by template with unique set of template-arguments is a unique type (template itself isn't a type).  it is possible to create template that would be statically or dynamically polymorphic, but that requires inheritance and QList isn't it.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want a QList<IParameter*>, you can do something like these:

```cpp
    QList<A*> la;
    QList<B*> lb;
    ...
    std::transform(lb.cbegin(),
                   lb.cend(),
                   std::back_inserter(la),
                   [=](B* b)
    {
        return static_cast<A*>(b);
    });
```

Comment: This code makes a copy, but is a casting possible?

Comment: No, just like Swift's said,  `QList<A*>` and `QList<B*>` are two different type.

Comment: @maestro casting also creates a copy. Casting of pointer is not safe and only reinterpret is allowed).

Comment: Did they refactor QList in late Qt versions? it used to have no cbegin/cend, but overloaded begin/end and some problems with iterating.